# Populating Prepared Statement with comma-separated list of integers

Tags: java, sql-server, prepared-statement

If I am populating a Prepared Statement

```
SELECT CODE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE COMPANY_NO IN (?)
```

How could I populate it correctly?

When I do

```
String sqlResult = "SELECT CODE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE COMPANY_NO IN (?)"

    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sqlResult, ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);

         ps.setString(1,"4,5");
   }
```

then I get

```
Arithmetic overflow error converting varchar to data type numeric.
```

which is because it is being populated as below:

```
SELECT CODE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE COMPANY_NO IN ('4,5')
```

Comment: Have you tried ps.setObject1, Arrays.asList(4, 5)) ?

Comment: Thanks - I tried this and it returned `The value is not set for the parameter number 1`

Comment: I took an idea from the question linked above and replaced SQL with `SELECT CODE FROM MY_TABLE WHERE COMPANY_NO IN (select * from dbo.splitString(?,','))` which worked